# python pandas yahoo data ETF

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I would like to fetch some ETF data from yahoo finance using pandas.

If I go onto the yahoo finance website, I can find the single ETFs (e.g. C001).

However, if I try to pull the data using python pandas, I get nothing.

```
df = pd.io.data.DataReader('C001','yahoo',start=datetime(2010,1,1), end=date.today())
```

The code works fine if I use 'AAP' instead of 'C001'.

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong? Is there a reason why 'yahoo' works but the ETF ticker symbols don't?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The second argument is the data source, so if you want data from Yahoo, this has to be `'yahoo'` (it can eg also be google or fred)

Comment: Thanks, how stupid. However, this still does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i noticed that on yahoo finance there are several tickers for C001 (C001.f,c001.de and so on).

i used some of my code(that include the ticker simbol too) and with C001F (or everything else) it worked fine.

```
 import datetime
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import DataFrame
 from pandas.io.data import DataReader
 symbols_list = ['C001.F']

 symbols=[]
 for ticker in symbols_list: 
     r = DataReader(ticker, "yahoo",
               start=datetime.datetime(20140, 01, 01))
     # add a symbol column
     r['Symbol'] = ticker
     symbols.append(r)
 # concatenate all the dfs
 df = pd.concat(symbols)

 print (df)
```

The result is this:

```
              Open    High     Low   Close  Volume  Adj Close  Symbol
Date                                                                 
2010-01-12   60.40   60.40   59.10   59.13    5100      59.13  C001.F
2010-01-13   59.30   59.81   59.30   59.81    3300      59.81  C001.F
2010-01-14   59.93   59.93   59.58   59.90     400      59.90  C001.F
2010-01-15   59.81   60.04   58.46   58.54    3400      58.54  C001.F
2010-01-18   58.93   59.09   58.91   59.09    4100      59.09  C001.F
2010-01-19   58.70   59.52   58.48   59.52   16700      59.52  C001.F
2010-01-20   59.39   59.52   58.42   58.46   89300      58.46  C001.F
2010-01-21   58.71   58.83   56.94   57.08   11800      57.08  C001.F
2010-01-22   57.19   57.19   56.17   56.17   14200      56.17  C001.F
2010-01-25   56.32   56.83   56.16   56.21   45700      56.21  C001.F
2010-01-26   55.72   56.60   55.71   56.60    4200      56.60  C001.F
2010-01-27   56.06   56.53   55.92   56.22     300      56.22  C001.F
```

Is that what you wanted to accomplish? (if you don't want the symbol ticker, don't use the lines after #add a symbol...) and change print df in print r.
I use symbol ticker 'cause i need to see symbols when i retrieve multiple tickers

Comment: Hi Andrea, that's pretty much what I wanted. The additional letter denotes the place where the stock was traded. Thanks a lot.